# Is there any way to open custom menu programmatically in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have [custom menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) in Google Sheets.

I'd like to open the menus programmatically with Google Apps Script, e.g. `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().getMenu().open()` .
But I can't find out the way.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: what do you means by open the menus

Comment: Open to do what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script cannot directly access user interface elements such as menus. You cannot programmatically "click" on a menu to make it show its menu items.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to interact with the UI, like performing clicks or opening menus.

You can execute the function that is being called by that menu.

So, if menu option A is execution function "foo", you can execute that function programmatically.

```
foo()
```